# Send mail from asp.net when application is not running

Tags: asp.net, email, send, offline

I want to send email on certain calendar days say 20th of everymonth. How can i do this? 
The problem is i am not so sure that this appliction will be browsed by users on 20th of the month. If not opened on this day, perhaps the mail can not be sent. Is there any way i can send it even if application is not running.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For this requirement I will write [**Windows Service**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) Application. Service will run on server without user intervention and will be dependent on users to login.

High level Action Steps will be

1. Store Calendar Days
2. Allow Service to access this store and send emails (using predefined template?) on requested Date time.