# Windows service to send mail on certain days

Tags: c#, windows, email, service

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Send mail from asp.net when application is not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13490630/send-mail-from-asp-net-when-application-is-not-running)

I am writing a windows service to send mail on certain days. I am using sql server table to identify on which days to send out mail, for this I need to check regularly. How can i achieve this.

I wrote code in `onStart()` event but it only works on Start. `OnContinue()` doesn't seem to work.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    eventLog1.WriteEntry("In OnStart");
    Test();
}

protected override void OnContinue()
{
    eventLog1.WriteEntry("In OnContinue."); 
    Test();           
}

void Test()
{
   //code to sendout mail
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a scheduled task. Why not create a "regular" program and set it up as a scheduled task rather than a service?

Comment: And also, the `OnContinue` is called when the service has been paused and becomes active again. Is that really what you intended?

Comment: This is also the same question you already posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13490630/279516